# Flutter App does not Connect to Firebase: MissingPluginException thrown

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am unable to connect my flutter iOS app to firebase. I have attempted running pub get, running flutter clean/flutter run, I have attempted creating a new project, all to no avail. I am new to flutter so apologies if I am doing something incorrect. The problem only seems to occur when I add "await Firebase.initializeApp();"

Thanks in advance and please see my main.dart, Pubspec.yaml and plist attached below. I've also attached a link to a screenshot of the error below

[image: Link to screenshot of error]

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:crumble/Pages/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:crumble/Pages/JoinScreen.dart';
import 'package:crumble/Pages/SettingsScreen.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
```

Required Plist for Flutter Plugin

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
```

Comment: If you have followed all the steps correctly to add firebase to flutter then close the running app and then run it again.

Comment: Did you already add the **google-services.json** and **GoogleService-Info.plist** to your flutter project?

Comment: @KeiCredo Ive only added the GoogleService-info.plist because I've only run an iOS app.

Comment: @HeckCodes I tried restarting the editor and simulator. Neither resolved the issue

Comment: Hmmm i'll try to check... if I may ask how did you add the GoogleService-info.plist to your project? is it thru xcode?

Comment: @KeiCredo - Thanks, I added the GoogleService-info.plist via Xcode.

Comment: I think you can just comment out the **firebase_core: ^1.12.0** in pubspec.yaml to solve it because firebase_auth can add the firebase_core by itself. Or you can also add **import FirebaseCore** in the AppDelegate.swift file as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue. It appeared to be an issue on the new M1 macbook's. Cocoapods needed to be installed using homebrew. Thereafter, once uninstalling, reinstalling and starting a new project the issue was resolved. Attached is a good video on how to do this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOjSNB7F2m4